# ifelse statement in R with different number of observations in tables

Tags: r, if-statement

I have datasets that look something like this called KN, ON, and NH3. (My table has 50000 observations though)

```
KN:
high  low   calc
 1     2     3
 2     2     2
NA     NA    4
 3     3     3

ON
high   low   calc
 1      2      3
 2      2      2
 2      2      2


NH3
high   low   calc
 1      1      1
 2      2      2
 3      3      3
 4      4      4
```

I would like to change my KN$low variable depending on this ifelse statement. (If KN$low is NA and ON$low/NH3$low are both not NA, then make KN$low= ON$low+NH3$low for that specific observation. Else, leave KN$low as it is)

```
KN$low <- ifelse(is.na(KN$low) & !is.na(ON$low) & !is.na(NH3$low), ON$low + NH3$low, KN$low)
```

So I'd want my output to look like this:

```
KN:
high   low   calc
 1      2     3
 2      2     2
 NA     5     4
 3      3     3
```

when I try to run this, I get this error:

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Which is because (I think) ON has less rows than KN and NH3.
Each observation in my table is matched with a station ID, so I think I'd have to use that somehow to pair observations for this ifelse statement (since I can't do it by observation number since each table has a different # of measurements)

Comment: In your examples, the number of rows are not the same and that is the warning you got.  Do you there is a common id where the datasets can be merged

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `match` command instead of `ifelse`.  I can't really answer your question as written because you aren't including the station ids, but assuming that all your data is stored in data frames, the answer will look something like this:

```
KN <- within(KN, {
  ON_low <- ON$low[match(KN$station_id, ON$station_id)]
  NH3_low <- NH3_low[match(KN$station_id, NH3_low)]
  low <- ifelse(is.na(low), ON_low + NH3_low, KN$low)
  rm(ON_low, NH3_low)
```

})

Comment: so I do the match statement first, and then ifelse?

Comment: yes, as written it replaces everything.  put an ifelse statement around it to replace only the NAs.

Comment: I just tried this: KN$KN_low <- KN$KN_low[match(ON$ss_id1, KN$ss_id1, NH3$ss_id1)] and I got his error Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, KN_UF_low, value = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.4,  : 
  replacement has 3082 rows, data has 16772

Comment: oops - I had KN and ON reversed.  Try now

Comment: But I have 3 tables, KN, ON, and NH3

Comment: As I said, that was the idea of the solution, not a final solution.  I've modified my answer to give you a more complete solution.  When you post a question, you need to give a complete representation of your data set - including (in this case) some variable identifying the stations.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to use `apply` as:

```
KN$low <- mapply(function(x){
      val = NA
      if(is.na(KN$low[x]) & !is.na(ON$low[x]) & !is.na(NH3$low[x]) ){
        val = ON$low[x] + NH3$low[x]
      }else{
        val = KN$low[x]
      }},1:nrow(KN))

KN
#   high low calc
# 1    1   2    3
# 2    2   2    2
# 3   NA   5    4
# 4    3   3    3
```

Since there are 50K+ rows, hence a `dplyr` based solution could be as:

```
library(dplyr)


KN %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(mutate(ON, rn = row_number()), by="rn") %>%
  left_join(mutate(NH3, rn = row_number()), by="rn") %>%
  mutate(low.x = ifelse(is.na(low.x) & !is.na(low.y) & !is.na(low), low.y+low, low.x )) %>%
  select(high = high.x, low = low.x, calc = calc.x )
#   high low calc
# 1    1   2    3
# 2    2   2    2
# 3   NA   5    4
# 4    3   3    3
```